# How can I properly format SQL files without faulty indentation?

Tags: sql, vim

I'm trying a myriad of online recommended packages for formatting SQL files and can't seem to get anything working. The output is always skewed. Does anyone have recommendations? I'm trying to pipe the file into a CLI tool while I'm writing statements/queries in VIM.

Example command: `sqlformat --reindent=true tables.sql`

```
sqlformat --reindent tables.sql                                                                                    2 ✘  11:36:17
CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
                                                         name VARCHAR(255),
                                                              email VARCHAR(255));
```

Ideal Output:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  email VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I did the following in my nvim init file

```
  115 "SQL Formatting
  116 nnoremap <leader>sql :%!sql-formatter-cli .<CR>
  117 inoremap <leader>sql :%!sql-formatter-cli .<CR>
```

after running `npm i -g sql-formatter-cli`

Comment: Better to set locally `equalprg` or similar.